# How to display a form in cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, nullreferenceexception

I've been trying to display a form using cshtml for quite some time and it's given me a lot of issues. I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

This is my Controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(Models.SearchModel user)
    {

        List<Models.SearchModel> UserList = new List<Models.SearchModel>();

        MySqlConnection connection = DBConnect.getconnection(); // setting connection to database
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetUsers", connection); // search for procedure called "GetData"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?search", MySqlDbType.VarChar)); // search parameters, if not looking for anythinf gets all the data
        cmd.Parameters["?search"].Value = "%" + "" + "%";
        cmd.Parameters["?search"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // telling program to read Data
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ID"]);
            string user_name = Convert.ToString(dr["user_name"]); // converting data to a string

            Models.SearchModel UserMod = new Models.SearchModel(id, user_name);

            UserList.Add(UserMod);

        }

        dr.Close(); // close

        DBConnect.CloseConnection(connection); // closes connection


        return View("Search");
    }
```

My Model:

```
 namespace AOSExpress.Models
 {
   public class SearchModel
 {
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string user_name;

    public string User_Name
    {
        get { return user_name; }
        set { user_name = value; }
    }

    public SearchModel(int i, string usnm)
    {
        id = i;
        user_name = usnm;

    }
}
}
```

and my Search.cshtml:

```
 @model IEnumerable<AOSExpress.Models.SearchModel>

 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "Search";
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }


 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   @Html.Partial("_SearchModel", item)
 }
```

and _Search.cshtml

```
  @model AOSExpress.Models.SearchModel

   <table style="font-family: Arial; border:1px solid black; width: 300px">
    <tr>
        <td><b>ID:</b></td>
        <td>@Model.Id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Username:</b></td>
        <td>@Model.User_Name</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The error is:

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_5m4f2la2.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Try not using Partial

Comment: you are passing a string "search" to your view while it is expecting a collection of search model

Comment: not really related to the problem, but are you sure you want a separate table for each result? or should they be rows of a larger table?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you are setting the view to the wrong `ActionResult`. In other words if you set the view to the `Search` with no code and just the `return View();` code, you will get a  `System.NullReferenceException` because the model is not within that method. Also, If all you want to do is display a table and not require user input there really is no need for `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]`.

So to fix this you might want to take the following steps:

**Cut all the code within the** `[HttpPost] Search` **and Paste it within the** `[HttpGet] Search`.

**Then completely erase the** `[HttpPost] Search` method.

**Then remove the** `[HttpGet]` **above the** `public ActionResult Search()` **along with the extra** `return View();` **you might have after copying the code over.**

Hope this helps.

Oh and make sure that you pass the model to the view `return View(UserList);`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing your list of SearchModels to the view. So Model in the view is null.

```
return View("Search", UserList);
```

This should resolve your issue.

Additionally, ASP-MVC is highly convention based. Since your action and the view have the same name (Search) you could omit the first parameter from your call to View:

```
return View(UserList);
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the full stack trace? 
If you debug this in Visual Studio, place a breakpoint near the beginning of Search() , does the exception occur before or after the breakpoint?